# Is a bridge rectifier needed to power LED lights from a DC Power Source such as a cordless tool battery?

Tags: power, dc

Is a bridge rectifier needed to power LED lights from a DC Power Source such as a cordless tool battery? Or can I simply wire direct from the battery to the light?

Comment: Basic answer is no, you don't need a rectifier. But you do need to regulate the current to the LED somehow. Either with a resistor or some electronic circuit. If you want more info, provide more information about the battery and LED or LED's.

Comment: "Is a bridge rectifier needed ... from a DC power source": no. The rest is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Basic circuit for powering a single LED from a battery

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJjpXx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

BUT, 'LED light' might mean any complex arrangement of multiple LED elements power supplies current limiters and so on.